# Scroll into view to a section wrongly when having lazy loading image inside body javascript

Tags: javascript, scroll, scrollview, lazy-loading

On my website, I have to use lazy load effect for images to optimize my website's performance `<img src="source_img" alt="img_alt" loading="lazy"/>`. But I have a problem if I have a `button` with a function go to a section inside this page. I use `element_scrolled_into.scrollIntoView({ behavior: 'smooth' })`. As naturally, when clicking this button, the page will scroll to the section added event. But the position scroll works wrongly because of the lazy loading image.

Demo: [Demo codesandbox link](https://codesandbox.io/s/little-fast-rr05he?file=/index.html)

Screenshot: [Deme screenshot](https://www.loom.com/share/a7a5115b51b74d0a9a11905eab218f0f)

First, it works wrongly, because at that time the image isn't loaded. After that, it works naturally, of course, the image is loaded, so having no bug here.

First, it works wrongly, because at that time the image isn't loaded. After that, it works naturally, of course, the image is loaded, so having no bug here.
Having any solutions to fix this bug?

Comment: not sure what youre expecting, seems to work on my end. Perhaps you can add a gif/screenshot or so.

Comment: @EricG My bad, I updated screenshot

Answer (score 1):

If I understand your problem correctly, it‘s about that the image wouldn‘t take the space and page jumps through image loading. It‘s important for rendering and to prevent this restyling to always provide `width` and `height` attributes for these assets like images.

Comment: Yes, correct. It's what I meant